# Orthographic projection - What is the process converting 3d point to 2d

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, 2d, projection, orthographic

I'm implementing a simple penalty shootout game using actionscript 3.0. The view of the game is similar to view of the old "Sensible World of Soccer". I want to use 3d game logic by using dimension z as I think that it could help me in order to achieve better collision detection - response results. However, I would like to keep the graphics style and view equivalent to old 2d soccers'. Hence, I assume that orthographic projection is suitable for this implementation. Although there is plenty of information in the internet regarding orthographic projection, I'm a little bit confused about how someone can apply it in his/her code.

So my questions are:

- Which is the procedure step by step in order for someone to convert a 3d (x, y, z) point to 2d (x', y') point in orthographic projection?
- Can we avoid using matrices? If yes, what are the equations that associate coordinates x', y' with x, y, z?
- Do we have to define a camera position and angle before applying the conversion? In my case, camera will be in a fixed position and angle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665653/flash-10-orthographic-projection?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

DisplayObjects and their descendants (ie MovieClip and Sprite) have a z property you can use to do this without the headaches - they also have rotationX/Y/Z and scaleX/Y/Z properties too!

Using 'z' will adjust the position and scale of an object accordingly (though it will convert vectors to bitmaps), there's no depth sorting, so it will stay on top of objects even if its z co-ord suggests it should be behind them, but for the project you have in mind I can't see this being a problem - it's pretty easy to fix anyway, have an array of objects in the scene, sort it according to z-position and reset the depth index of each/re-add to stage in sorted order.

You can use the perspectiveProjection member of a clip to adjust the FOV, origin etc -

[Perspective Tutorial](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/pp/)

..but you don't need to get any more sophisticated than that. Certainly you don't need to dabble with matrices with a fixed camera view, even if you wanted to calculate this manually as an experiment.

Hope this helps